# Microsoft Access How to display information from 1 table for 2 other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I am having difficulties getting my report working. I have a purchaseOrder table which contains 1 address ID, which represents the shipping address. The vendor associated to the purchaseOrder also has a address ID, which represents the billing address.

Here is the relationship in case you got confused with my explanation.
[image: Relationship]

I am wondering how to tell my report that the address record belongs to vendor or purchaseOrder. Any advice or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Report PO]

The raw SQL of the query, ignore the long select.

```
SELECT tbl_purchaseOrder.ID, tbl_purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderDate, tbl_vendor.salesContact,   tbl_vendor.phone, tbl_vendor.extension, tbl_vendor.fax, tbl_vendor.vendorNo, tbl_vendor.vendorName, tbl_address.address, tbl_address.city, tbl_address.provinceOrState, tbl_address.postalCode, tbl_address.country, tbl_purchaseOrder.shipVIA, tbl_purchaseOrder.FOB, tbl_purchaseOrder.term, tbl_PODetails.quantityOrder, tbl_rawItemList.ItemSerialCode, tbl_PODetails.dueDate, tbl_PODetails.unitCost, tbl_PODetails.unit, tbl_rawItemList.description, tbl_PODetails.specialInstructions, tbl_purchaseOrder.requistionedBy, [unitCost]*[quantityOrder] AS Total
FROM tbl_rawItemList INNER JOIN (((tbl_address INNER JOIN tbl_purchaseOrder ON tbl_address.ID = tbl_purchaseOrder.addressID) INNER JOIN tbl_vendor ON (tbl_vendor.ID = tbl_purchaseOrder.vendorID) AND (tbl_address.ID = tbl_vendor.addressID)) INNER JOIN tbl_PODetails ON tbl_purchaseOrder.ID = tbl_PODetails.purchaseOrderID) ON tbl_rawItemList.ID = tbl_PODetails.rawItemListID
WHERE (((tbl_purchaseOrder.ID)=[Enter a PO number:]));
```

Comment: You will be able to based on the alias given to `tbl_adress`.  You should have two aliases since you are linking to it twice. Can you show us what the query looks like?

Comment: just a quick thoughts: Why are you having a standalone Address table? each vendor has his own address, each client/buyer has his own address. you won't save database space by having standalone address table because you are going to type the address for each vendor anyway..

in your case: you need to add two address table one for vendor, one for purchase order and get the address from purchaseorder_address table

Comment: @krishKM at the time, it seem logical since I needed address in 5 different table, so I thought it would be easier to just create 1 table for it, and assign a AddressType to it.

Comment: @Linger Did you want a picture of the Query GUI, or SQL format?

Comment: The actual sql statement.  Then we can tell you exactly how to reference the two different addresses.

Comment: @Linger I added the SQL statement into the main question.

Comment: @Joshua Dalley, see my answer for a detailed explanation of what you need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to do is link to `tbl_Address` twice as shown below:

[image]

Here is the what your FROM clause should look like:

```
FROM ((((tbl_PODetails 
INNER JOIN tbl_rawItemList ON tbl_PODetails.rawItemListID = tbl_rawItemList.ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_purchaseOrder ON tbl_PODetails.purchaseOrderID = tbl_purchaseOrder.ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_vendor ON tbl_purchaseOrder.VendorID = tbl_vendor.ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_address AS POAddress ON tbl_purchaseOrder.AddressID = POAddress.ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_address AS VendorAddress ON tbl_vendor.AddressID = VendorAddress.ID;
```

Notice that I am linking to `tbl_address` twice and I am giving them aliases of `POAddress` and `VendorAddress`.  So, to get the address information for the vendor you would bind your controls to : `VendorAddress.address`, `VendorAddress.city`, and etc.

The address fields you have in your SELECT statement would have to be changed to:

```
POAddress.address, POAddress.city, POAddress.provinceOrState, POAddress.postalCode, POAddress.country, VendorAddress.address, VendorAddress.city, VendorAddress.provinceOrState, VendorAddress.postalCode, VendorAddress.country
```

So your complete query should look something like:

```
SELECT tbl_purchaseOrder.ID, tbl_purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderDate, 
       tbl_vendor.salesContact, tbl_vendor.phone, tbl_vendor.extension, 
       tbl_vendor.fax, tbl_vendor.vendorNo, tbl_vendor.vendorName, 
       tbl_purchaseOrder.shipVIA, tbl_purchaseOrder.FOB, tbl_purchaseOrder.term,   
       tbl_PODetails.quantityOrder, tbl_rawItemList.ItemSerialCode, 
       tbl_PODetails.dueDate, tbl_PODetails.unitCost, tbl_PODetails.unit, 
       tbl_rawItemList.description, tbl_PODetails.specialInstructions, 
       tbl_purchaseOrder.requistionedBy, [unitCost]*[quantityOrder] AS Total, 
       POAddress.address, POAddress.city, POAddress.provinceOrState, 
       POAddress.postalCode, POAddress.country, VendorAddress.address, 
       VendorAddress.city, VendorAddress.provinceOrState, 
       VendorAddress.postalCode, VendorAddress.country
FROM ((((tbl_PODetails 
     INNER JOIN tbl_rawItemList ON tbl_PODetails.rawItemListID = tbl_rawItemList.ID) 
     INNER JOIN tbl_purchaseOrder ON tbl_PODetails.purchaseOrderID = tbl_purchaseOrder.ID) 
     INNER JOIN tbl_vendor ON tbl_purchaseOrder.VendorID = tbl_vendor.ID) 
     INNER JOIN tbl_address AS POAddress ON tbl_purchaseOrder.AddressID = POAddress.ID) 
     INNER JOIN tbl_address AS VendorAddress ON tbl_vendor.AddressID = VendorAddress.ID;
WHERE (((tbl_purchaseOrder.ID)=[Enter a PO number:]));
```